# WSO2 API Manager Interface

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am trying to use WSO2 API Manager, however it selects the wrong network interface when started. I think this in turn makes it select the wrong interface on which to find my API implementation. Does anyone know how you specify the correct interface that is selected?

Comment: What do you mean by wrong interface? If you are connected to internet WSO2 API Manager will use your IP. Or else you can use https://localhost:9443/carbon

Comment: @jamdung : Could you please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Though your question is not much clear,hope you want to login to WSO2 API Manager.

Port offset 0.

- Admin console :https://localhost:9443/carbon
- Publisher    :https://localhost:9443/publisher