# API Manager Server Multiple Network Interface - WSO2 Error when Start

Tags: api, wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

I am using the API Manager wso2 but when I have two network interfaces for example: Interface one = data (192.168.1.10)
         Interface two = network backup (172.10.10.10)

when I start API Management in the configuration that have variables for example:
tcp://${carbon.local.ip}:${jms.port}

The Ip Address in log to appear with error.

Example:
wso2carbon.log:TID: [-1] [] [2016-11-08 11:05:22,763]  INFO {org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnection} -  Unable to connect to broker at tcp://172.10.10.10:5673 {org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnection}
wso2carbon.log:TID: [-1] [] [2016-11-08 11:05:45,475]  INFO {org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnection} -  Unable to connect to broker at tcp://172.10.10.10:5673 {org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnection}
wso2carbon.log:TID: [-1] [] [2016-11-08 11:06:25,487]  INFO

The correct IP Address should tcp://192.168.1.10:5673 and not 172...

**I imagine that be the same issue. [WSO2 API Manager Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30475791/wso2-api-manager-interface)**

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can set required IP or Hostname in `carbon.xml` for `HostName` and `MgtHostName`.

```
<!--
   Host name or IP address of the machine hosting this server
   e.g. www.wso2.org, 192.168.1.10
   This is will become part of the End Point Reference of the
   services deployed on this server instance.
-->
<!--HostName>www.wso2.org</HostName-->

<!--
Host name to be used for the Carbon management console
-->
<!--MgtHostName>mgt.wso2.org</MgtHostName-->
```

Also, you have to replace `${carbon.local.ip}` in all configuration files by required IP/Hostname too.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response